# How to send data to another computer with C# like hyperterminal does through modem

Tags: c#, modem, hyperterminal

I need to create a program that lets me send a string of data or a file through modem, like hyper-terminal does.  Im trying to create a program that lets me send electronic billing data to Medicare, and since Medicare only accepts e-bills through modem, only hyper-terminal or another program called PC ACE Pro32 can be used.

I want to create my own program, since hyper-terminal is not user friendly, and the other program has too many things for just sending data.

I've never before had experience creating code for data communication.  Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of pieces here, so let me break this down into sub questions for you:

1) How do I do serial communication in C#?

There are plenty of examples on the internet. A quick search turns up [this one](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/) and [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/serialportcommunication12082008111137am/serialportcommunication.aspx), both of which seem to be ok. There are also lots of questions here on SO about C# serial communication.

2) How do I control a modem?

Modems are operated by some version of the [AT command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command_set). If you're familiar with manually operating a modem in HyperTerminal, you're essentially doing the same thing, but in code. For example, to test if your modem is paying attention (i.e., that your serial line is talking to the modem properly), you send `AT`, and see if the modem replies with `OK`. To dial, you send the modem `ATDT <phone number>`. Once a modem establishes carrier, then whatever you send down the serial port is transmitted to the remote computer.

3) How do I communicate with medicare's electronic claims system?

This one is up to you! I'd be surprised if they didn't have a web-based claims service though. I would expect that would be a lot easier than doing it over a modem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a receiving connection in remote computer.
2. Set up a connection to remote computer just like any dial-up connection.
3. Use socket programming (TCP) to send/receive data to/from remote computer. Note that you must create a client/server application that resides in both remote and local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Seth, your answer is actually very promising.  Ill be taking a look at those suggested links right away.

(yes, medicare should be moving to ethernet, but reality is that they are stuck in dialup because they say that "it's more secure than ethernet", when in reality it's not.

Comment: This needs to be a comment to the answer, and not an answer to your question.